# i am trying to use text to speech library in android but it does not have manifest file nor is eclipse project

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech

I am trying to use text to speech library in android but it does not have manifest file nor is eclipse project  this is the url which library i wanted to use https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/467#package.

How can i use text to speech library to get the text be converted to different voice male or female?

Answer (score 0):

Android platform has built in [TextToSpeech system](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html).